# Is it possible to retain the form(html) content data after page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please give me a good suggestion but without using Ajax.
I mean to say is it possible to do in JavaScript/J query or else.

My Issue : When i am submitting one page, the action class again return to this same page
now as per my requirement i have to retain the state of some radio button and checked boxes checked as it checked before.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: localstorage or for support of older browser cookies. Basically, use any persistant storage method

Comment: Without ajax you could append them via query string params, then send them right back.

Comment: Thanks you so much Neil ,can you please give me a example

Comment: what code are trying ???

Comment: Tushar i am trying to solve this using JSP ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the form data (state of the form) in a session, which will involve setting cookies or local storage, some of which may be implemented using JavaScript.

If I were doing it, I would store the values from my form in session variables and then repopulate the form when I return to the page.

This can be done using a server side scripting language such as PHP or JSP or .net

An example of how to get started with JSP, I suggest the following tutorial:

http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp

Comment: Sorry Marc Audet can you please give more clarification , and i am using jsp, so please suggest me 

Thanks again for your quick feedback

Comment: Thanks Marc i am appreciate with u

Comment: You are welcome! If you have a chance, update your SO profile with a short description of your skill set, that way, when people try to answer your questions in the future, they can better judge how to best write answers.  Good luck with the work!

Comment: Just curious, why did you unaccept the answer? Sessions did not work?

Answer (score 1):

If the form action redirects to the same page, i.e. you want to repopulate the same field that was just sent on the same page, you can just enter the form data as default value:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" value="<?=$_POST['name']?>" />
</form>
```